# Cant cope with an error (destructor destroys everything)

Tags: c++

I face this problem:

```
No source available.
Call stack location: lab5.exe! Counter:: 'scalar deleting destructor'() + 0x2b bytes.
```

I construct a single linked list.

**counter.h**

```
class Counter{
    private:
        char* m_pStr; 
        unsigned int m_nOwners; 
        Counter* pNext;         
        static unsigned int m_curCounters;
        static Counter* Head;   
...
```

**counter.cpp**

```
Counter* Counter:: Head = new Counter();
unsigned int Counter:: m_curCounters = 0;

Counter:: ~Counter(){
    if  (this == Head){
        Head = Head->pNext;
    }
    else{
        Counter* current = Head->pNext;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_curCounters; i++){
            if (current->pNext == this){
                            // Searching for counter, with next one equal this.
                current->pNext = this->pNext;
                break;
            }
            current = current ->pNext;
        }
    }
    m_curCounters--;
    delete[] this->m_pStr;
}
```

The closing brace leads to the error. In the pictures: one step separates me from the error screen and the error itself.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

P.S. Vectors are forbidden.

Comment: Read about the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: By the way, please show your constructor as well. You _do_ set e.g. `pNext` to `nullptr` there?

Comment: Well, I have read it thank you. But I still can't see my fault.

Comment: I also recommend you read http://sscce.org/.

Comment: If instances of the class can be copied or assigned, then you need to do a _deep_ copy, not only copy the pointer or all copies will share the same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class needs to follow the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.
You need to provide a copy constructor & copy assignment operator which perform deep copies of the dynamically allocated data members.

Alternatively, You can use a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer. This will save you all the explicit manual memory management.

Also, you are much better off replacing `char *` with `std::string`.

Comment: I failed to construct these two constructors as Head is static.

Comment: Its [rule of 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) since C++11 :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: True, but I don't really think OP is using C++11.